# Recursive match function with cyclic function dependences

Tags: ocaml

I'm not sure that the title explains my problem, but I can improve it after for the moment I want to explain my problem because are several days that I'm breaking my mind over this problem.

I'm developing a static analysis for my class with Ocaml to check if my c (subset of a C language) program meaning somethings real, and I'm new with this stuff (with the language and paradigm and with the compiler stuff).

The static analysis is traversing the Abstract syntax tree (Ast) and make some checks of it (The check is a problem with TODO comment), for the moment I'm developing the data structure, in particular a Symbol Table, and implementing the code to traverse the Ast.

My complete Ast.

```
type binop = Add | Sub | Mult | Div  | Mod | Equal | Neq | Less | Leq |
             Greater | Geq | And | Or | Comma
             [@@deriving show]

type uop = Neg | Not [@@deriving show]

type identifier = string [@@deriving show]

type position = Lexing.position * Lexing.position
let dummy_pos = (Lexing.dummy_pos, Lexing.dummy_pos)

type 'a annotated_node = {loc : position[@opaque]; node : 'a}[@@deriving show]

type typ =
  | TypInt                             (* Type int                    *)
  | TypBool                             (* Type bool                   *)
  | TypChar                             (* Type char                   *)
  | TypArray of typ * int option         (* Array type                  *)
  | TypPoint of typ                      (* Pointer type                *)
  | TypVoid                             (* Type void                   *)
  [@@deriving show]

and expr =  expr_node annotated_node
and expr_node =
  | Access of access                 (* x    or  *p    or  a[e]     *)
  | Assign of access * expr          (* x=e  or  *p=e  or  a[e]=e   *)
  | Addr of access                   (* &x   or  &*p   or  &a[e]    *)
  | ILiteral of int                  (* Integer literal             *)
  | CLiteral of char                 (* Char literal                *)
  | BLiteral of bool                 (* Bool literal                *)
  | UnaryOp of uop * expr            (* Unary primitive operator    *)
  | BinaryOp of binop * expr * expr  (* Binary primitive operator   *)
  | Call of identifier * expr list   (* Function call f(...)        *)
  [@@deriving show]

and access = access_node annotated_node
and access_node =
  | AccVar of identifier             (* Variable access        x    *)
  | AccDeref of expr                 (* Pointer dereferencing  *p   *)
  | AccIndex of access * expr        (* Array indexing         a[e] *)
  [@@deriving show]

and stmt = stmt_node annotated_node
and stmt_node =
  | If of expr * stmt * stmt         (* Conditional                 *)
  | While of expr * stmt             (* While loop                  *)
  | For of expr option * expr option * expr option * stmt (* For loop *)
  | Expr of expr                     (* Expression statement   e;   *)
  | Return of expr option            (* Return statement            *)
  | Block of stmtordec list          (* Block: grouping and scope   *)
  [@@deriving show]

and stmtordec = stmtordec_node annotated_node
and stmtordec_node =
  | Dec of typ * identifier          (* Local variable declaration  *)
  | Stmt of stmt                     (* A statement                 *)
  [@@deriving show]

type fun_decl = {
  typ : typ;
  fname : string;
  formals : (typ*identifier) list;
  body : stmt;
}[@@deriving show]

type topdecl = topdecl_node annotated_node
and topdecl_node =
  | Fundecl of fun_decl
  | Vardec of typ * identifier
  [@@deriving show]

type program = Prog of topdecl list [@@deriving show]
```

My problem is how to traverse the `stmt` because inside contains the `Block of stmtordec list` and the `stmtordec` and have the `stmt` and in this case, I'm in a cyclic dependence that I'm not able to resolve with the match function.

My idea to traverse it is to have an OCaml function `check_stm` -> `check_blk` -> `check_stm`, but how I can resolve this idea with the code?

At the moment my code is that but don't compiler because I'm not able to put the function in the OCaml scope at the same time.

My code is that

```
open Ast
open Symbol_table
open Easy_logging

let logger = Logging.make_logger "Semant" Debug [Cli Debug]

(* Global Scope: This scope contains all the Global declaration
   Global declaration types:
   - Int, Bool, Char, Array.
   - Struct
   - function declaration
*)

let global_scope = empty_table

let check_blk blkstm =
  match blkstm.node with
  | Ast.Dec(tipe, id) ->
    begin
      logger#debug "Variable declaration check";
      (* TODO: I'm missing the variable duplication *)
      Symbol_table.add_entry id tipe global_scope
    end
  | Ast.Stmt(stm) ->
    begin
      logger#debug "Stm check (recursive call)";
      check_stm stm
    end

let check_stm node =
  match node with
  | Ast.If(ex, ifs, els) -> logger#debug "TODO: If stm check"
  | Ast.While(ex, stm) -> logger#debug "TODO: While stm check"
  | Ast.For(ex1, ex2, ex3, stm) -> logger#debug "TODO: For stm check"
  | Ast.Expr(ex) -> logger#debug "TODO: Expression check"
  | Ast.Return(optex) -> logger#debug "TODO: Return stm check"
  | Ast.Block(blkstm) -> List.iter check_blk blkstm


let check_fundec node =
  match node with
  | fun_decl as f ->
    begin
      logger#debug "Checking function declaration";
      (* TODO: how I can managed the parameter of the function?*)
      global_scope = Symbol_table.begin_block global_scope;
      check_stm f.body.node
    end


let rec match_type ast_elem =
  match ast_elem.node with
  | Vardec(tipe, id) ->
    begin
      logger#debug "Global variable found";
      add_entry id tipe global_scope;
      ()
    end
  | Fundecl(fundec) ->
    begin
      logger#debug "Function analysis found";
      Symbol_table.add_entry fundec.fname fundec.typ global_scope;
      check_fundec fundec;
    end


let check (Ast.Prog(topdecls)) = List.iter match_type topdecls
```

Maybe this question is foolish, and maybe I'm making something wrong inside my idea, but I want to talk about the problem to fix it and learn how to use the OCaml language

p.s: For the moment the `Symbol_table` implementation is an empty implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you just have to specify the mutually recursive functions explicitly. You do so using the `and` keyword, just like with type definitions, but also have to use the `rec` keyword because function definitions are not recursive by default, unlike type definitions:

```ml
let rec check_blk blkstm = ...

and check_stm node = ...
```

Comment: Thanks, you understand my problem and also you fixed it, but I can ask you want is the meaning of the and keyworkd? Thank you

Comment: `and` is needed to bring later definitions into scope. Without it you can only refer to definitions from further up in the file.